# play framework: http requests : server : get(),post(),put() - can't understand how it works

Tags: http, post, playframework, get, server

Soooooo, i've looked around and tried to understand how the 'http' requests are working ... i've tried some methods, but i failed 'with flying colors' (ok, sorry for that). 
I think i have problems understanding how everything works....

For example...I have this register form:

```
@(page: String, isLoggedIn: Boolean, userInfo: NewUser)

@import bootstrap3._

@Main(page, isLoggedIn, userInfo) {

    <script src='@routes.Assets.at("javascript/index.js")'></script>
    <br><br><br>

   <br>
    <form action="@routes.Application.addUser()" method="POST">

    <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-4">
    <h3><b>Register : </b></h3>
    <br>
    Username :
    <input type="input" name="username" class="form-control"><br>
    First Name :
    <input type="input" name="first_name" class="form-control"><br>
    Last Name :
    <input type="input" name="last_name" class="form-control"><br>
    Password:
    <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control"><br>
    Repeat Password : 
    <input type="password" name="re_password" class="form-control"><br>
    <input type="submit"  class="btn">
    </div>

    </form>

}
```

with this model:

```
...
public class NewUser extends Model{

    @Id
    public String Id;

    public String username;
    public String first_name;
    public String last_name;
    public String password;
    public String re_password;

 +getters and setters

}
```

And i want to make a method to add the user to my database using my server...

```
 public static Result addUser(){

      String url = "http://localhost/my-server-url";      
      NewUser user = Form.form(NewUser.class).bindFromRequest().get();


//    ? String charset = "ISO-8859-1";
//   ?  WSRequest wsRequest = WS.url(url);

//   ? HttpResponse wsResponse = wsRequest.post();
//    ? String responseString = wsResponse.getString(charset);
}
```

********** And what now ... !? - how does the server know how to fill my database? (i think the url helps here ... the register form should have the same structure like my DB?)
   *********Or how can i tell him to give me back something from the data base in a list (for example)?

---

Can someone please explain how it all works !?
Thanks a lot ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How does the server know how to fill my database?the register form should have 
>   the same structure like my DB?

**Play** contains several different `bind()` methods. Some of them supports JSON or request values, the others `Map<String, String[]>` instances. They all point internally to `public Form<T> bind(Map<String,String> data, String... allowedFields)` method. As the name of this method suggest, it's responsible for handling submitted data. It means that inside this method we can find a fragments about:

received data normalization (translation the unordered data to interpreted object, in this case DataBinder instance):

```
DataBinder dataBinder = null;
Map<String, String> objectData = data;
if(rootName == null) {
    dataBinder = new DataBinder(blankInstance());
} else {
    dataBinder = new DataBinder(blankInstance(), rootName);
    objectData = new HashMap<String,String>();
    for(String key: data.keySet()) {
        if(key.startsWith(rootName + ".")) {
            objectData.put(key.substring(rootName.length() + 1), data.get(key));
        }
    }
}
```

So the line

```
Form.form(NewUser.class).bindFromRequest()
```

in your controller creates an form object of `NewUser` type and maps the request coming to the `NewUser` object fields interlnally as shown above code.So the form field name should be same as your entity fields name in order to be persisted in database.

> And what now ... !?

Now after doing

```
 NewUser user = Form.form(NewUser.class).bindFromRequest().get();
```

in your controller you have to pesist this entity by doing

```
user.save();
```

It will be saved in database.You can also send this object to you model call save method there.

> How can i tell him to give me back something from the data base in a
>   list (for example)?

Souppose you have to find all the NewUser saved in database .So you can fetch the list by

```
public static Finder<Integer, Member> find = new Finder(Integer.class, NewUser.class);
public static List<NewUser> all(){
        return find.all();
    }
```

in your model class and call this `all()` method in your controller .

You can always take help from play [samples](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.0/Samples) provided in folder that you downloaded.

Note: I am assuming here you are using default orm of play i.e. ebean

[Source1](http://www.waitingforcode.com/play-framework/forms-and-validation-in-play-framework/read) [Source2](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaForms)

Comment: I can't understand .... who is 'data' ? ... i  can see it is from : public Form<T> bind(Map<String,String> data, String... allowedFields) ... but ... who is it ? how do i add that : public Form<T> bind(Map<String,String> data, String... allowedFields) ? ...

Comment: @Mădălina I showed you the internal code of play you have to do nothing with it you just have to `Form.form(NewUser.class).bindFromRequest()` and rest of the things play will handle

Comment: omg, it is that simple !? ok, thank you ... i hope i am doing a good work here. Thanks for answering .... Do you know when i have to use my server and a http request ? if i can save data so simple , why do i need those kind of things ? like ws respons... and others !?